# When working with files, is it preferable to store file in variable or use 'with' on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, comparison, coding-efficiency

Which is the best of these two? Why?

Variable option:

```py
file = open('rabbits.txt')
party = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

Or 'with' option:

```py
with open('rabbits.txt') as file:
    party = file.readlines()
```

Comment: There is no difference. Using `with` is just more convenient, as you don't have to remember to close the file.

Comment: You can even use it to read and write to more than one file. See [here](https://cmdlinetips.com/2016/01/opening-a-file-in-python-using-with-statement) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, statement 'with' helps to shorten our code a little bit, because we do not need to close the file at the end. Additionally, it is a nice option for opening multiple files at once like this:

```py
with open('rabbits.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file, \
     open('rabbits_lowercase.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as first_file, \
     open('rabbits_uppercase.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as second_file:
    for line in input_file:
        first_file.write(line.lower())
        second_file.write(line.upper())
```

Furthermore, the statement 'with' is considered to introduce a context manager on Python for effective managing of resources.